# Why do I get this IOerror13 ? Using python

Tags: python, ioerror

```
import sys
import os
import re
import ftplib

os.system('dir /S "D:\LifeFrame\*.jpg" > "D:\Python\placestogo.txt"')   #this is where to search.
dat = open('placestogo.txt','r').read()

drives = re.findall(r'.\:\\.+.+',dat)
for i in range(len(drives)):
    path = drives[i]
    os.system('dir '+ path +'\*.jpg > D:\python\picplace.txt')
    picplace = open('picplace.txt','r').read()
    pics = re.findall(r'\w+_\w+.\w+..jpg|IMG.+|\w+.jpg',picplace)
    for i in range(len(pics)):
        filename = pics[i]
        ftp = ftplib.FTP("localhost")
        print ftp.login("xxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxx")
        ftp.cwd("/folder")
        myfile = open(path,"rb")
        print ftp.storlines('STOR ' + filename, myfile)
        print ftp.quit()
        sys.exit()
```

i am trying to copy all of those files to my ftp server but it gives me that error:

```
d:\Python>stealerupload.py
230 Logged on
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\stealerupload.py", line 22, in <module>
    myfile = open(path,"rb")
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: '"D:\\LifeFrame"'
```

any one knows where is the problem ? I am running as administrator and folder should have permissions

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with your error, but please consider using the `glob` module to search for files, rather than using `os.system`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems pretty obvious.  You are trying to open a directory path, which is neither possible nor what you actually want to do.  This bit:

```
for i in range(len(drives)):
    path = drives[i]
    ...
    for i in range(len(pics)):
        ...
        myfile = open(path,"rb")
```

Inside the loop you are setting `path` to be one of your `drives` elements.  each of these items appears to be a directory path.  Then you try to open `path` later, which is a directory path and not a file.

Comment: You might try `os.path.join(path, filename)`.  As is, your code is really suboptimal.  You don't need to iterate of the range of lengths, you can just iterate over `drives` or `pics` directly.  Also, as mentioned in the comment to your question, the `glob` module would probably be better for you.  At the very least, have a look at the `os.walk` module.

Comment: ` os.path.join(path, filename) ` yields the same error unless Iv'e put it in wrong line...  also I am a begginer programmer :). and is there a way around this problem ? or do i need to run another `os.rename()` line for each picture and upload it

Comment: Just doing the path join isn't what you want.  You need to assign it to something.  For example: `file_path = os.path.join(path, filename)` just below where you do `filename = pics[i]`.  Then `open(file_path, 'rb')` instead of `open(path, 'rb')`.  Finally, you're going to get weird results with your loops.  You're using `for i in range(len(drives))` and `for i in range(len(pics))`.  Those `i`s aren't stored differently for each loop.  Use a different variable for the second loop and anything referencing that value.

Comment: Thanks you very much ! program runs successfully also I have made it deal with exceptions! big thanks to everybody!

Answer (score 0):

In the error message, it shows `'"D:\\LifeFrame"'`, which to me looks like you have extra quotes in `path`. Try adding `print path` to see what its value is.

Maybe you want to upload data from `filename` to your server, not from `path`, in which case Python showed in the error message is where the bug is: you should be opening `filename` instead.

Comment: Hmm, nothing new. Try changing `myfile = open(path, "rb")` to `myfile = open(filename, "rb")` and see if that's it.

Comment: (Note that if that *does* fix the bug, it will still only upload one file, because of the `sys.exit()` call inside the loop.)

Comment: '
230 Logged on
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\stealerupload.py", line 22, in <module>
    myfile = open(path,"rb")
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: '"D:\\LifeFrame"' 
'

Comment: but if i put the 1.jpg into python directory it works onley for it and keep giving errors on other jpg's

Comment: You need `os.path.join`, as paidhima says, because you need to pass `open` a full path to the file you want to open. Right now, it's looking for the file in the current directory, just like any command would.